# Displaying Actionscript Documentation in Eclipse

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, actionscript-3, flash-builder

This is probably a very basic question, but how does one enable the actionscript documentation to appear properly in Eclipse? For example, if you hover over `addChild`, the ASDoc view brings up the class hierarchy with `flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer.addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject`, but does not give any of the details, descriptive text, parameters, etc. If I write my own documentation using the `/** */` format, it does appear in there. What have I done wrong? :P

I'm using the Helios version of Eclipse with Flash Builder 4. Thanks!

Comment: I have same problem also with Galileo.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about something like following:

[image: ASDoc in Flash Builder]

then, it is available in Flash Builder. You might want to try it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have replied a long time ago - but this isn't actually answering the question. I *am* using FlashBuilder, as that's a plugin for Eclipse. This was mentioned in the last line of my question. Unfortunately, my trial period for Flash Builder ran out a long time ago so this is no longer relevant...

Comment: I meant 'standalone' flash builder. Not plugin.